# Jcrop does not work on ie 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Im using jCrop http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html and there is a weird problem

it wont work while im in ie8

if I was on ie8 and select document mode ei7 from developers tools it works fine

what can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the latest version? Seems there is an IE8 fix:

http://deepliquid.com/blog/archives/142

Edit: Strangeness ahoy! It only works after i turn on compat. mode, then turn it off o_O. My IE8 window was open from an earlier test and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

can you test with the [latest and greatest version on github](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop)? It has major MSIE updates. I am currently working on a blog post announcing this release.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is dealt with [here](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/issues/detail?id=67), which is a bit of a hack to hide the radio button

Comment: I don't see that this is answering the question above at all.